# How to conclude that $f$ may not have a fixed point

Tags: continuity

Let $f:[0,1)\rightarrow [0,1)$ be a continuous map.How to conclude that $f$ may /may not have a fixed point?

I tried to prove this fact considering the function $g(x)=f(x)-x $ then $g$ is continuous $g(0)=0$

But the proof does not hold as in the case for$[0,1]$

Comment: Find a counter e.g. say like $2-\sqrt 2^{1-x}$.

Answer (score 1):

The segment $[0,1)$ is homeomorphic to the ray $[0,\infty)$. If you find a function $f:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ with no fixed point, you can thus deduce the existence of such a function $[0,1)\to[0,1)$.